# Why isn't my form resized correctly when on shown or load event?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, window-resize

I have a form with:

```
DataGrid
SaveButton
CancelButton
```

Positioned one under another. I call the folowing method when the form is shown and resized:

```
private void resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int totalRowHeight = thresholdsDataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in thresholdsDataGridView.Rows)
                totalRowHeight += row.Height;

            thresholdsDataGridView.Height = totalRowHeight; 
            this.Height = totalRowHeight + closeButton.Height + saveChangesButton.Height;
        }
```

This works well when resizing but when showing it it does not add enough height (the bottom button is not shown). Can someone shed some light on this?

Screenshot of the desired result:

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to use [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte(v=vs.80).aspx) to set your control's position, which will be auto adjusted to the size of your window.

Comment: Have you considered putting your controls in something like a `TableLayoutPanel`, where such things are handled automatically?

Comment: @DonBoitnott I haven't since I'm new to this, I'll try that if this fails

Comment: @Bolu I have set up the ancor to top-left, how do I set up the form to wrap the content?

Comment: I believe based on your question, you should set `DataGrid` to `top left right and bottom`; both buttons to `left bottom`

Comment: @Bolu now the buttons overlay the `DataGrid` and why is pressing undo not get me back to where I was? it's all a mess now

Comment: fixed it back, redocked everything at top

Comment: where did you put your control in the first place, and I was talking about using `Anchor` only, remove other settings (like `Dock`) and your `resize` method. Can you post a simplified screenshot?

Comment: @Bolu posted the result I want so far the close button is not shown until I resize it (columns hidden)

Comment: Based on your illustration, you should set `DataGridView`'s `Dock` property to `Fill`, and those two buttons' `Dock` to `Bottom`. And I suggest you to start with a new Project, add just those three controls, and play with it until you get get familiar..

Comment: the buttons overlay the entries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54206/discussion-between-bolu-and-mihai-bratulescu).

Comment: You forgot about the border, set the ClientSize property instead.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have every control placed over each other. To make this design simpler, set:

Buttons' anchors to: **"Bottom, Left, Right"** and DataGridView's anchor to: **"Top, Bottom, Left, Right"** in designer.

**Then add this variable to your form's class' root:**

```
int originalHeight;
```

**Set the "originalHeight" in your form's constructor:**

```
originalHeight = this.Height;
```

**Then each time a new row is added, run:**

```
private void resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int rowsHeight = thresholdsDataGridView.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
   this.Height = originalHeight + rowsHeight;
}
```

Comment: This is a very, **very** bad idea.  The actual Height of a form is not predictable, it depends on the user preferences for the size of the caption text and buttons.  Winforms avoids this by using the ClientSize property instead.  And on the DPI setting of the user's video adapter, Winforms avoids this by auto-scaling.  Please revise or remove your answer, it is not helpful right now.